# Getting page to load completely before getting the content

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey, document-ready, gm-xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to use `$(document).ready(function()` to get the page to fully load before using the ajax but for some reason it's not working properly. I am only able to get only part of the page, because it does not wait for it to fully load before getting the content.

Which part of the code can I fix to fix this?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test1
// @namespace   John Galt
// @description Basic Google Hello
// @match       *://www.google.com/*
// @version     1
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

 $(document).ready(function(){

 GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method: "GET",
    url:    "http://www.fictionpress.com/",
    onload: function (response) {
        var parser = new DOMParser ();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString (response.responseText, "text/html");
        var theString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc);
        document.write(theString);
    },
    onerror: function (e) {
        console.error ('**** error ', e);
    },
    onabort: function (e) {
        console.error ('**** abort ', e);
    },
    ontimeout: function (e) {
        console.error ('**** timeout ', e);
    }
} );

    });
```

Comment: are you sure the page is not fully loaded? There may be other on page ready code performs further DOM mutation

Comment: @Ji_in_coding Yeah the website looks only partially loaded.

Answer (score -2):

You can add an option:
`// @run-at document-end`. That says Tampermonkey that you're need to wait full page loading.

Full list of the options can be found [here](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php).